# How to add/create features in postgis layer without geometry?

Tags: qgis, postgis

I have a Postgis layer loaded in QGIS 2.8.6. There is empty POINT geometry field that I have to fill with geographic information.

[image: table in postgres]

How do I add features to this layer without adding new geometries? My intention is to complete the point field geometry with coordinates information.

[image: postgis layer loaded in QGIS]

For exemple, for the row 0 I have all the information but I have to complete it with the geometry information (In this case, UTM information).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured this out! (also asked [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52671/adding-a-gis-feature-to-existing-database-entry-with-qgis))

A record in a spatial table (Shapefile, PostGIS, Spatialite) that has no geometry can have geometry added by adding a 'part' to the feature using the advanced digitizing toolbar. Here's the workflow:

1. Bring table containing the geometry-missing feature into QGIS
2. Select the layer from the layers panel and start an edit session on
   that layer
3. Right-click the toolbar area of QGIS (where there is no button) and
   open the advanced digitizing toolbar
4. Open the attribute table of the layer and select the feature that is
   missing geometry
5. On the advanced digitizing toolbar, click the add part tool
6. You can now add the geometry of the feature (point, line, or
   polygon) as you would add any new feature to a table
7. Save your edits, and stop editing.

   The feature now has geometry!

Comment: thanks, this was remarkably non-straightforward.